# cakephp find order sorting with associated fields

Tags: php, cakephp, model

```
Array
(
        [Site] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [parent_id] => 0
                [title] => test
                [url] => http://www.test.com
                [slug] => www_test_com
                [keywords] => cpc,seo
                [language_id] => 1
            )
        [SiteMeta] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [site_id] => 1
                        [key] => pagerank
                        [value] => 5
                        [created] => 2010-08-03 00:00:00
                    )
             )
)
```

By using cakephp, I debug my find('all') and returned me above array. I can sort Site field values by order value inside find function how I am able to order also with SiteMeta values

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in the Model as part of the association.

```
$hasMany = array('SiteMeta'=>array('order'=>array('SiteMeta.value'=>'asc')))
```

You won't have to repeat yourself anywhere then.

Comment: that is the way already in pocket thanks but a lot of customized sort functions using the model currently so

Answer (score 1):

you can use a default query with a order condition like this:

```
$result = $this->Site->find('all', array(
      'order'=>array('SiteMeta.value DESC' , 'Site.value DESC'),
      'recursive'=>1));
```

Obviously you can  put a condition inside the array to retrieve your right result

Comment: okay but what I am in need of is to order SiteMeta.value and Site.value.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way (as shown in the [Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sorting-contained-associations))

```
$result = $this->Site
  ->find()
  ->contain([
    'SiteMeta' => [
      'sort' => ['SiteMeta.pagerank' => 'ASC']
    ]
  ]);
```